# Set initial value in liquibase with postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, liquibase

I have a table and i need that it's ID start in 1000000. 
I have this code set for liquibase:

```
        <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true" startWith="1000000">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
```

But it does not work in postgres, the generated sequence generator starts with 1.
Does anyone has any idea on this? How can i enable a table to start from a value in liquibase that works with postgresql?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: PostgreSQL has serial types: `serial` and `bigserial`, which by default start with 1 and are incremented by 1. I'm not familiar with liquibase, but in case it allows you to deal with sequences, you can try `ALTER SEQUENCE your_seq RESTART WITH 1000000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just alterSequence won't help:

```
    <alterSequence 
            minValue="1000000"
            sequenceName="t1_id_seq"/>
```

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: START value (1) cannot be
>   less than M INVALUE (1000000) [Failed SQL: ALTER SEQUENCE
>   public.t1_id_seq MINVALUE 1000000]

and according to docs you can't start sequence with [alterSequence](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/alter_sequence.html), so you have to [createSequence](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_sequence.html) with

```
<createSequence 
        sequenceName="seq_id"
        startValue="1000000"/>
```

and then "assign" it as default value to your bigint column

```
  <sql dbms="postgresql" endDelimiter=";\n"  splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true">ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('seq_id');
  </sql>
```

or initially use bigserial and sql to restart sequence:

```
<changeSet author="Vao" id="1">
    <createTable tableName="t2">
        <column name="id" type="bigserial">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="t2_pkey"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="Vao" id="2">
  <sql dbms="postgresql" endDelimiter=";">ALTER SEQUENCE t2_id_seq restart with 1000;
  </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately startWith don't seems to work for postgres db.
You can use (with yaml configuration) :

```
- changeSet:
  id: add-auto-increment-postgres
  author: me
  dbms: postgresql
  changes:
    - createSequence:
        sequenceName: my_sequence
        startValue: 1000
    - addDefaultValue:
        columnName: id
        defaultValueSequenceNext: my_sequence
        tableName: my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx! Drop and create new - helps

1. dropSequence
2. createSequence